# Building WSN topology integrated with SDN controller (mininet-wifi)

Tags: python, emulation, sdn, mininet, openflow

In mininet-wifi examples, I found a sample (6LowPAN.py) that creates a simple topology contains 3 nodes.
Now, I intend to create another topology as follows:

> 1- Two groups of sensor nodes such that each group connects to a 'Sink
>   node'
>
> 2- Connect each 'Sink node' to an 'ovSwitch'
>
> 3- Connect the two switches to a 'Controller'

Is that doable using mininet-wifi? Any tips how to do it??

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with 6LowPAN.py. You then add switches and controller into the topology with their links.